# Is Cauchy–Riemann equations total derivative or partial derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

One was trying to work on some proofs of the "extended" Cauchy-Riemann equation with some more "variables". However, the expression usually wrote as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial u }{\partial x} =\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial u }{\partial y} =-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

In two dimension, this did not create the ambiguity of the partial derivative and the total derivative. However, with more variables,(and potential additional constrains) does $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ meant the partial derivative, or actually the total derivative

$$\frac{du }{dx }=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{dv}{dy}$$

Is Cauchy–Riemann equations total derivative or partial derivative?

Comment: What you are calling total derivative has no meaning in this setting.

Comment: @TedShifrin it's more like say suppose $u(x,y,n,m)$ and $v(x,y,n,m)$ with $g(x,y,n,m)=0$ etc. the generalization with more variables.

Comment: There are no constraints in play in the Cauchy Riemann equations. I don't know how you are thinking to generalize them, but I don't see any reason why they would suddenly appear.

Comment: Without a constraint curve or something, $y$ and $x$ are independent variables in the plane. So there is no $\partial y/\partial x$ to use in any equations, regardless of your intent.

Comment: Since you mention more variables, if you're actually working through material on several complex variables, it might help to tag your question with that. Either way, a concrete example of what you mean by "extended CR" and the situation you're worrying about would help us help you. From a basic complex analysis standpoint, one would never really consider CR on a constraint curve (but it'd still be the partial derivative and not the total derivative if you had one). I'm not posting an answer because I fear I haven't understood your context properly.